# Finding the rightmost point that satisfies a given set of inequalities

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

I have 8 inequalities, 4 y>= (dashed lines) and 4 y<= (continous lines). Reading graph I can determine solution area (grey area). For me most interesting is only most right point of solution area. Now i need to do somethig similar but without graph uing only some algorithm. So does exist any methot/algorithm to do that or something similar? Or any other tips how to try find that point mathematically?  Ofc image below is only example, I'm looking for method, not solution of this example.

[image: 8 inequalities]

Answer (score 1):

You region consists of some linear constraints, and you would like to solve the linear optimization problem to maximize $x$ subject to your constraints.

You can use, for example, the [Simplex Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) to do that.

There are also useful implementations in all conceivable programming languages I know, please specify if interested in anything specific. Here is one implementation for Python to get you started [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, turn the inequalities into lines by using an equals sign in place of the inequality sign. Then take every possible pair and find their point of intersection. Then, substitute each intersection point into the original system of inequalities to see if it lies on the solution region. Of all of the points that work, take the rightmost one (the point with the highest $x$-coordinate), and that is your answer. If two points have the highest $x$-coordinate, they are both solutions, along with the entire line in between them.